# python binding for enable_if_t<is_same_v<U, void>>

Tags: c++, pybind11

I need to bind for a fun of set(), which is defined as below:

```
template<typename U=T> std::enable_if_t<!is_same_v<U, void>> set(U const& val)
{
   set_value(val);
}

template<bool _Cond, typename _Tp=void>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
```

I tried to bind for the return type (std::enable_if_t<>):

```
void bind_enable_if_t(py::module &m)
{
    py::class<std::enable_if_t<bool, OutputDataType> pyClass(m, "enable_if_t", py::module_local()); 
}
```

I got error messages:

```
In function 'void bind_enable_if_t(pybind11:module&)':
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type'

note: expected a constant of type 'bool', got 'bool'
```

What is the meaning of "expected a constant of type 'bool', got 'bool''?
What'll be the correct way to do the binding?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `enable_if_t` is a type alias used to implement SFINAE. It is not itself a class template. I don't think it makes sense to define a binding for it. The return type of the function is just `void`.

Comment: @user17732522, thanks for your attention. If enable_if_t shouldn't be binded. Maybe I should ask how to bind a function: set(void) : std::enable_if_t<bool3 19 is_same_v 2 #65536 33 0, void>. Do you have an idea or suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly my experience with pybind11 is very limited, but when the function is instantiated it just has return type `void` (If `T` is not `void`) or it doesn't exist at all (if `T` is `void`). There should be no need to do anything than bind the member pointer in the former case, e.g. `.def("set", &whateverclass::set<>)`.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t` accepts **a** `bool` as its first template argument, not `bool` itself (which is a type, not a value).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you have an SFINAE decorated method, you can help the compiler resolve the correct method to bind via

```
using T = MyConcreteType;

// ...
.def("set", &Class::template set<T>)
```

and without the `&Class:: template` part if its a free standing function.

In your case, since `set` is completely disabled for `void` types, I would furthermore put the `.def` in an `if constexpr(!is_same_v<U, void>)` guard.